# Array model binding from only one control

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

That`s the deal
I have a array on my model

```
public string[] Estrofes { get; set; }
```

and I have a textarea on my view

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Estrofes)
```

What I want is split what is inside the TextArea using the blank line as the separator and put each string separated in a position in my array

For Example...

If user input:

FirstLine

SecondLine
OtherStuffs

ThirdLine
Blablabla
Etc

The Array must receive...

[FirstLine,SecondLine OtherStuffs,ThirdLine Blablabla Etc]

There is a way to do this directly by ModelBiding ?

Comment: Not unless you were to create a custom `ModelBinder`. Why not just do it in the POST method?

Comment: I made this. I made the logic I need in the POST method, but I'm searching for a more elegant way to do this logic. I'll search for the custom ModelBinder you talk, Thanks